# Origin of the phrase "send tell"?

Tags: phrases

"Send tell" aka PST and similarly Mt is commonly used in video games and online chat programs. To me, it sounds like something out of the renaissance.   What is the origin of the phrase?

Comment: Unable to delete comment on iphone

Answer (score 2):

From the World of Worldcraft [wiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/PST):

> PST is an acronym for Please Send Tell. It originated from older
>   online games, MUDs, and MMORPGs such as EverQuest, which used [the
>   command] /tell to send private messages to other play[er]s.

Comment: I am not confident in the articles accuracy.  As I recall I used this phrase in chat rooms well before these games came into existence.  Mid 90s

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the commands in early MUDs and MMORPGs were based on earlier chat software.

Comment: Sounds like an old IRC command to me.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Certainly there were popular MUDs in existence before the 90s. Things move fast on the Internet!